# Update mysql table using CASE subquery with limit

Tags: mysql, sql-update, subquery, case

I want to run below query to update **Vouchers** table

```
UPDATE vouchers SET status = 6 WHERE voucher_id IN 
               (
                  select a.voucher_code from products a 
                  JOIN order b ON a.order_id = b.id 
                  WHERE a.voucher_code != '' LIMIT 10
               )
```

but when running the query, I am getting below mysql error :

**This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving your subquery into an update join:

```
UPDATE vouchers v
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.voucher_code
    FROM products a 
    INNER JOIN order b
        ON a.order_id = b.id 
    WHERE a.voucher_code != ''
    LIMIT 10
) t
    ON v.voucher_id = t.voucher_code
SET v.status = 6;
```

`LIMIT` should be allowed in this case.